# Error while running executable made from cmake app with wine on wsl2

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wine

When I run wine Vanadium.exe from cmake-build-debug folder, the wine returns me an error.
Everything I did I did on wsl2 (Ubuntu 22.04)

```
0040:err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_seh-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\mnt\\c\\Users\\Administrator\\CLionProjects\\Vanadium\\cmake-build-debug\\Vanadium.exe") not found
0040:err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\mnt\\c\\Users\\Administrator\\CLionProjects\\Vanadium\\cmake-build-debug\\Vanadium.exe") not found
0040:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"Z:\\mnt\\c\\Users\\Administrator\\CLionProjects\\Vanadium\\cmake-build-debug\\Vanadium.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have the MinGW runtime dlls: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449769/distribute-a-program-compiled-with-mingw-g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449769/distribute-a-program-compiled-with-mingw-g)